# Gerar PDF a partir de seletor na página corrente com CSS

Tags: jquery, css, pdf

Gostaria de saber como faço para gerar um PDF a partir de um seletor que eu defino e que toda a formatação desse seletor venha corretamente no PDF?

Quero fazer client-server. Exemplo: Imagine que eu tenha uma página completa, dai tenho uma área especifica que tem um gráfico, quero gerar um PDF, mas o conteúdo do PDF vai ser somente o do gráfico. Você pode tomar como exemplo o `printElement` que imprimi um elemento. O que eu quero seria assim:

```
$( '#minhaDiv' ).gerarPDF();
```

Serve também em arquivo, não precisa ser exatamente o que tenho na página corrente, mas, desde que o CSS não seja omitido no momento da geração.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com `gerar um PDF a partir de um seletor`? E quer fazer do lado do cliente ou servidor?

Comment: Quero fazer client-server. Exemplo:
Imagine que eu tenha uma página completa, dai tenho uma área especifica que tem um gráfico, quero gerar um PDF, mas o conteúdo do PDF vai ser somente o do gráfico. Você pode tomar como exemplo o `printElement` que imprimi um elemento. O que eu quero seria assim: `$( '#minhaDiv' ).gerarPDF();`

Comment: achei esse tópico no SO-en: [Export HTml page to PDF on user click using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786113/export-html-page-to-pdf-on-user-click-using-javascript)

Comment: Testei a solução do link acima e não consegui sanar meu problema. O código simplesmente não roda.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja falando de marcações/propriedades CSS, se você quer que reconheça propriedades CSS, recomendo o **mPDF**, porém deve utilizar marcações até CSS 2.1 e esta é uma biblioteca PHP, ou seja, deverá gerar o PDF no lado servidor.

Recursos:

- Aceita UTF-8
- Suporte ao CSS
- Relacionar o item
- Suporta imagens JPEG, GIF, PNG, WMF e SVG
- Marca d'água
- Biblioteca PHP Standalone
- Etc...

Veja todos os recursos em http://mpdf.bpm1.com/index.php?page=Features

Download: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download

Comment: Vou testar ele hoje.